# Flask how to make html page show up?

Tags: python, html, flask

Okay so I will just have some reading to do. I don't expect anyone to answer anymore. Thanks for everybody that took the effort to reply.

I have followed the following guide to create a simple python app: https://guillaumegenthial.github.io/serving.html

edit:
Okay retrospectively I should have read more stuff before asking this question. Let me try to rephrase what I am trying to do.

I am trying to access the below defined html page. There I want to input text in a textbox and then process that text in the api function defined in flask. The results I then want to output inside the html page.
I tried to find some more ressources on this, but I am new to html and flask and am struggeling. 
Any tips would be appriciated.

My app.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from serve import get_model_api

app2 = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app2) # needed for cross-domain requests, allow everything by default
model_api = get_model_api()

# default route
@app2.route('/')
def index():
    return "Index API"

# HTTP Errors handlers
@app2.errorhandler(404)
def url_error(e):
    return """
    Wrong URL!
    <pre>{}</pre>""".format(e), 404

@app2.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(e):
    return """
    An internal error occurred: <pre>{}</pre>
    See logs for full stacktrace.
    """.format(e), 500

# API route
@app2.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
def api():
    input_data = request.json
    output_data = model_api(input_data)
    response = jsonify(output_data)
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app2.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=81, debug=True)
```

The html file:

```
<body>
    <div class="container col-lg-6">
        <div style="padding-bottom: 0.5cm">
            <div class="card text-center bg-light">
                <div class="card-body" style="padding-bottom: 0.2cm">
                    <input class="card-title form-control" type="text" id="input" name="input" placeholder="Input sentence"/>
                    <button class="card-text btn btn-outline-primary" id="btn">Find Entities</button>
                    <button class="card-text btn btn-outline-primary" id="btn2">Get random Tweet</button>
                    <div class="spinner" id="spinner" style="display: none">
                      <div class="double-bounce1"></div>
                      <div class="double-bounce2"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer bg-white">
                    <pre class="card-text api-pre" style="padding-bottom: 0.2cm">
                        <div class="item" id="api_input">Nur der HSV </div>
                        <div class="item" id="api_output">0 0   B-ORG</div>
                    </pre>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function api_call(input) {
        // hide button and make the spinner appear
        $('#btn').toggle();
        $('#spinner').toggle();

        $.ajax({
            url: "0.0.0.0:81/api",
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(input),

            success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                // toggle the spinner and button
                $('#btn').toggle();
                $('#spinner').toggle();

                // fill the html for answer
                $('#api_input').html( data.input );
                $('#api_output').html( data.output );

                $("#input").val("");
            },
            error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                $('#btn').toggle();
                $('#spinner').toggle();

                $('#api_input').html( "Sorry, the server is asleep..." );
                $('#api_output').html( "Try again in a moment!" );

                console.log( errorThrown );
            },
            timeout: 3000 // sets timeout to 10 seconds
        });

    }

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        // request when clicking on the button
        $('#btn').click(function() {
            // get the input data
            var input = $("#input").val();
            api_call(input);
            input = "";
    });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: This is really unclear. Are you trying to access the `/api` route in a browser? If you are - you've explicitly defined that route to only accept POST requests (from your AJAX); trying the route in a browser is a GET request, which you've excluded. No fix is needed.

Comment: for /api decorator, use `methods=['GET', 'POST']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding `/api` you are only making a GET request and that is all that is defined:

```
@app2.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
def api():
    input_data = request.json
    output_data = model_api(input_data)
    response = jsonify(output_data)
    return response
```

If you want the information available for testing, you can just add the GET method like so:

```
@app2.route('/api', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

However, I think you may want to read up on HTML request methods to see what is the most appropriate type for what you are making the endpoint do.

I'm guessing the tutorial information is expecting a POST for the api, which is common. A simple example of a POST request can be done from most commandline with curl:

```
curl -X POST MYIP/api -d "{ \"myKey\": \"myValue\"}"
```

This should return whatever response that is given by the api method.

Comment: Allowing GET requests would work for a browser too, but I have a feeling that the plain JSON response might not be what they expected :)